# Good quality graphing control for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need a library for line/bar/pie charts as well as grids (like excel) - I love and am failure with Kendo and would like something similar - but their $1000 price for MVC is outside my budget

Tips?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) library. It's freeware js library for building a lot of type charts.